# How to convert a function in Async/await?

Tags: typescript, async-await, nativescript

I am trying to convert this function in async/await:

```
   finddevice(s: any) {
        if (s !== '') {
            for (let i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
                this.ws.ping(s + '.' + i).subscribe(res => {
                    console.log('res', res)
                    if (res) {
                        try { throw i }
                        catch (ii) {
                            let myipfind = s + '.' + ii;
                            this.myipdevice = myipfind;

                        }
                    }
                },(error) => {
                    console.log('got error from finddevice', error);
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

I follow [Async/await](https://pointdeveloper.com/async-await-javascript-typescript/) and try to change my function. However, nothing happens, wrong answers don't stop.

```
   promiseFun(){
  this.s = `${this.myip & 0xFF}.${(this.myip >> 8) & 0xFF}.${(this.myip >> 16) & 0xFF}`
     return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            if (s !== '') {
              for (let i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
                  this.ws.ping(s + '.' + i).subscribe(res => {
                       if (res) {
                         try { throw i }
                           catch (ii) {
                              let myipfind = s + '.' + ii;
                                this.myipdevice = myipfind;
                             }
                            }
                        },(error) => {
                            console.log('got error from finddevice', error);
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            setTimeout(()=>{
                resolve("Resolved");
                },2000);
               })
              }

    async makeCall() {
        try {
          let successData= await this.promiseFun();
          console.log(successData);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      }
```

The correct answer is reached, but the wrong answers still do not stop.

Any idea how to stop the wrong answer?

Comment: You have wait for results before running next ping, do next ping only if last ping was failed.

Comment: How? Can you modify my code please?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to convert this function in async/await:

Just use `toPromise` and you will be able to await e.g.

```
await this.ws.ping(s + '.' + i).toPromise();
```